# HF/HV - rectification or modulation?

Tags: autotransformer

Lets put it simply:

1. The aim is to rectify the high frequency/high voltage (i.e. 200 kHz, 100 kV) output to 12-24-48 V DC.

or

2. Modulate (possible amplitude modulation?) the HF/HV output with 50 Hz.

and compare which one of these two methods is more efficient at the output.

The question is how to rectify the HV/HF Tesla secondary(L2) output. What are (if there are any) the appropriate diode rectifiers that are capable of handling HF and HV outputs?

Comment: Yet another victim of the free energy stuff. Tesla knew what he was doing, very well. He never claimed that his aparatus can produce a free energy. He just sent the energy from a power line into the air, not an insignificant achievement even for nowadays.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we don't do over-unity energy scams here.

Comment: The question was how to rectify the HV/HF tesla secondary(L2) output.  What are(if there are any) the appropriate diode rectifiers that are capable to handle HF and HV outputs?

Comment: @raiden777 It might be helpful to draw a circuit for both methods, make sure you actually ask a question in the post. I'll edit it

Comment: _”200 kHz, 100 kV”_ How did you manage to produce that?

Comment: I bought the VCO(Voltage Controlled Oscillator)/PLL(Phase Lock Loop) tesla coil from the Aliexpress.  PLL helps to hold the resonance frequency between L1/L2, which is important if you try to mess around with extracting the power from the L2 output.  I don't really trust the measurement using my off the shelf frequency/voltage meter though. But probably somewhere close to those values.  Often these PCB boards that run TT coils have some form of modulator/interrupter in them commonly used for musical tesla coils, but I might need the magnetic field modulation or supply power interruption??

Answer (score 2):

> I've come across the discussions where some engineers believe that the air core resonant transformer can have super high efficiency of transformation/energy saving potential

Adding resonance to an air-core transformer makes it more efficient than it would have been without.

However normal transformers are close to 100% efficient already, so developing a chain of converters in the search for even higher efficiency is doomed to failure.

If you are seeking better than 100% efficiency, then dream on. We don't do over-unity on this site.

Tesla coils are strictly for

a) where you want lots of pretty sparks (sole purpose of 99.9% of all Tesla coil builds)

b) where you need high voltage and some isolation between input and output, and can tolerate the losses and inconvenience of this sort of transformer.

If you want the rectified output to be 12-24 V eventually, then it would make sense for your Tesla secondary to be a few turns of wire loaded with an appropriate capacitor for resonance, producing the ballpark of your target voltage, rather than many turns producing a high enough voltage for the pretty sparks effect.

Comment: Oh boy... Where does this "additional energy" come from, exactly?

Comment: @raiden777 Pour your free energy soup into your over-unity tin-foil hat. We don't do perpetual motion on this site, we observe the conservation of energy. There are plenty of other sites you can go to where they'll pander to fruit-loopery.

Comment: I bet they measured those output voltages and currents separately...